# Is there a terminology for this scene transitioning technique?

Tags: film-techniques

In movies such as ***One Last Dance***,

We see:

- Time stamp: 0:01, a pair of hands being washed off blood, this pair of hands opening up is transitioned from a bullet blown up someone's brain (but this video clip does not show this shooting part)
- Time stamp: 0:08, Water dropping into a kitchen sink which transitions into a spinning car wheel

It is common for a movie director to use this kind of transitioning technique, either by sound or by visual. I am wondering if there is a terminology for it?

Comment: I don't know why people are VTCing this for being unclear. It seems rather straightforward to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These transitions are called ***match(ed) dissolves*** or ***match cuts***.

[Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/match_dissolve) definition of a '*match dissolve*' is

> A technique by which one picture merges into another having the same or a similar object in the same place; an example of this.

As pointed out by [the Wikipedia article on match cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_cut), an iconic example is the transition used in *2001: A Space Odyssey*, where a bone spinning around in the air transitions into a space ship:

[image: A famous example of a match dissolve in Kubrick's 2001]